# Cambiar el valor de un objeto en una lista

Tags: c#, lista

Quiero cambiar el nombre de O2 a M2 despues de haber iniciado la lista intente esto pero pone (Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int')

```
void Start()
{
    var cartasOro = new List<string>() { "O1", "O2", "O3", "O4", "O5", "O6", "O7", "OJ", "OQ", "OK" };
    cartasOro["O2"] = "M2";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cartasOro` es una lista, no un diccionario. Para leer o modificar un elemento de cualquier lista, así como los arreglos, indicas su posición entre corchetes.

"O2" está segundo, así que si posición es la 1. Por lo tanto, el código correcto es:

```
cartasOro[1] = "M2";
```

Si desconoces la posición, puedes averiguarla con [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-8.0):

```
int posicion = cartasOro.IndexOf("O2");
if (posicion != -1)
    cartasOro[posición] = "M2";
```

Si estás aprendiendo, no dudes en ver [este tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/arrays-and-collections).

Comment: Si la función IndexOf no encuentra el elemento devolverá -1 y esto significa una excepción en el código que muestras, ya que -1 no es un índice válido para los arreglos en c#, te recomiendo hagas esta validación, saludos